# How to create .appx package for Universal Windows Platform(UWP) application?

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have created package for my universal windows platform application.But I am not able to find where the .appx file is generated for my package.
It has generated .appxbundle file and all the other files.But .appx file is not generated.

Answer (score 1):

An `.appx` is just a zip64 file, and a `.appxbundle` is a zip file containing such zip files.

If you use `makeappx.exe` you can extract all the files inside your `.appxbundle` and see the individual `.appx` files within.

```
MakeAppx unbundle /p bundle_name.appxbundle /d output_directory
```

See [App packages and deployment (Windows Runtime apps)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hh464929?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [App packager (MakeAppx.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446767.aspx#extract_package)

Comment: Note that MakeAppx will add an AppxBlockMap.xml to the zip as a signature of the content, so while you can unpack using zip, it's not so easy to create one by simply zipping some folders

Answer (score 1):

The .appxbundle is like the name suggest a bundle of .appx files. This is actually a zip file containing .appx file.

You can choose not to create .appxbundle files but create separate .appx files if needed

[image]

Set "Generate App Bundle" to never

Answer (score 0):

You can find the appx file in the dependencies folder of the app package under the ARM folder.

AppPackages-->Dependencies-->ARM