# APPX4001 warning

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

The following warning appears in my UWP project. I have already marked examples of solutions but I am more interested in why this warning does not occur when creating another empty project on the same platform?

```
APPX4001: Build property AppxBundlePlatforms is not explicitly set and is 
calculated based on currently building architecture. Use 'Create App 
Package' wizard or edit project file to set it.
```

Comment: Hi friend, what's your vs version? And your target version, APPX4001 seems to be a known error but I can't reproduce it in my latest version VS2017 and VS2019. Could you share some details about the project which get this warning? So I can reproduce and check it.

Comment: The target version does not matter when I made a copy of the project and changed it and the warning still occurs. In addition, it seems to me that this warning was not in my project, but I do not know exactly when it appeared.

Answer (score 3):

Simple workaround for APPX4001 warning see [this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/331223/view.html).

> But I am more interested in why this warning does not occur when
>   creating another empty project on the same platform?

I searched the related info about this warning and found this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46072032/xamarin-forms-localization-of-the-uwp-app?rq=1). See `...\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2459,5): warning ...`, so it seems that this warning is thrown by the `Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets` file. Not sure why the warning sometimes doesn't show where it come from, but I think the targets file is the cause of APPX4001.

I found that file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage`. (for vs2017 enterprise) Let's check its content which throw the warning:

[image]

So it's obvious that if the value in Condition is true, it will throw warning APPX4001. It seems that this issue have something to do with the `AppxBundle`. So I create a new uwp project and build it, all is ok. And then I add this line into its xx.csproj file:

```
<AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
```

Then the same warning occurs:

[image]

So this warning will occur if you try to `build with Appxbundle or set the AppxBundle property in project file` while you didn't set the AppxBundlePlatforms property.

This is the reason why new simple project won't display this warning. And simple workaround for this warning is to set the AppxBundlePlatforms property, see the first line in my answer.

Hope all above can help resolve the puzzle why the warning comes and resolve the warning.
Let me know if I misunderstand anything :)

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. APPXBundle is not in my project file. Is there an option where you can turn it on / off or extractplatforms set to false?

Comment: @robko Maybe [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35554022/10910450)? Can you share the project file which has this issue in your question, then I can check the difference between mine.

Comment: @Lance Li-MSFT Thanks for the very detailed answer. Can you please explain exactly where to insert the line `<AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>` in the .csproj file?

Comment: It's too long since I posted the answer... I don't remember that well...  I think you can just put it in a single <PropertyGroup>. Note you'll get the warning above if you set this property.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this link](http://www.spritehand.com/2015/10/appxbundleplatforms-and-windows-uwp-app.html) can help.

As described in the article, I tried to package my App (just used Sideload package without signature). 
The packaging process then added the

```
<AppxBundlePlatforms>x86|x64|arm</AppxBundlePlatforms>
```

entry in the .csproj file and the warning has disapeard

Answer (score 0):

On Unity, where the C++ project is being generated on-the-fly (editing is pointless),
one can pass `/p:AppxBundlePlatforms=x86|x64|arm` as an argument to `MSBuild.exe`.